# How to tell JAXB that order of elements does not matter?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

Is it possible to tell JAXB to ignore the order of elements? So that the generate XSD will contain `all`-elements instead of `sequence`-elements?

Comment: What are you referring to?  XJC (i.e. schema to java) or schemagen (i.e. java to schema)? Technically, neither one of these is part of JAXB.

Comment: Maybe `JAXBContext.generateSchema()` is meant?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add an [`XmlType`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) annotation to the class with an empty `propOrder`, like this:

```
@XmlType(propOrder={})
public class MyClass{
    String username;
    String street;
    String address;
}
```

It will then generate an `xs:all` (which is unordered) instead of a sequence.

```
<xs:complexType name="MyClass">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```