# Converting Java Object to XML in the order of Schema xml

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a java object

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
    private String id;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "phone-number")
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

I want to define a schema xml (customer.xsd) which should be used to set the order of tags while generating xml, 
The Object to xml generated should be like below in different order compared to object members order.

```
<customer>
    <startDate></startDate>
    <endDate></endDate>
    <name></name>
    <id></id>
    <phoneNumbers></phoneNumbers> 
</customer>
```

Both the Marshalling and Unmarshalling code should be based on the same schema xml.

Can someone help me how to create this schema and how to achieve my ordering??

Comment: Have you tried writing the XSD? Where you got stuck?

Comment: I tried xsd, approach i think now the xml is generated but, the tags are in the order of fields set to the VO, not in xsd tags order. Also there is a linked exception related to some order of the fields. Is there anything else i have to do??

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- In the Java Object you can define `@XmlType(propOrder={<order of the elements>})`
  Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712760/how-to-tell-jaxb-that-order-of-elements-does-not-matter) for more details.
- Second approach (Using xsd), you can define a xsd like this:

> ```
> <xsd:element name="Customer">
>   <xsd:complexType >
>        <xsd:sequence>
>           <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
>           <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" />
>           <xsd:element name="startDate" type="xsd:string" />
>           <xsd:element name="endDate" type="xsd:int" />
>           <xsd:element name="phoneNumbers" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
>        </xsd:sequence>
>   </xsd:complexType>
> </xsd:element>
> ```

In the XSD you can order the elements inside the  `<xsd:sequence>`
Please note, I have not tried with this XSD for this example, I added it for your reference.

Comment: tried with the xsd approach. The order of members in object and xsd are different. Populated the object and tried marshalling. Getting some order of fields error like below.                                                             Invalid content was found starting with element 'address'. One of '{gender}' is expected.

Comment: Could you please post the exact error you are getting along with the xsd file?

Comment: <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="agentVO">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="gender" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="agentCode" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="agentDesc" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="idNumber" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="dob" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="contact" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Comment: ERROR: Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'address'. One of '{gender}' is expected.]
 at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
 at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
 at com.ndfs.ncp.jax.JaxMarshaller.main(JaxMarshaller.java:33)

Comment: Just found that the xml generated in alphabetical order, Is there a way to suppress this and get the xml in original xsd format??

Comment: @BalajiKannan I am not sure, I have to check. As per my understanding, the XML should get generated according to the sequence provided in xs:sequence.